# splitting a data frame by date and computing median for all rows with each date

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date, median

I am attempting to roughly estimate that amount of work than could have been done by staff for a given month.

I've got a csv that looks roughly like this (although it's a lot bigger):

```
+--------+-------+---------------+
|  Date  | Name  | Units of Work |
+--------+-------+---------------+
| 1/1/17 | Bob   |           450 |
| 2/1/17 | Alice |           300 |
| 2/1/17 | Bob   |           450 |
| 2/1/17 | Larry |            50 |
| 3/1/17 | Alice |           400 |
| 3/1/17 | Bob   |            11 |
| 3/1/17 | Larry |           100 |
| 4/1/17 | Alice |          1000 |
| 4/1/17 | Bob   |           240 |
| 4/1/17 | Larry |            33 |
+--------+-------+---------------+
```

I want to:

1. Compute the median 'Units of work' for each 'Date'
2. Determine if any 'Name' did less than 20% of the median 'Units of work' for that 'Date'
3. Remove 'Name' if it did fewer than 20% of the median
4. Multiply the count of 'Name' left for the 'Date' by the median 'Units of work' for that 'Date'
5. Output a new csv that has each 'Date', appearing only once, on its own row, and that date's median 'Units of work' multiplied by the remaining 'Name' for that 'Date'

I can't even meet requirement 1, much less 2 through 5.  I'm getting one file for **each date**.  And instead of a column with the median, I get a new column called 'NewColumn' filled with the word 'median', like so:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('source.csv')
df = df.sort_values('date_trunc').assign(NewColumn='median')
df.median(axis=None, skipna=None, level=None, numeric_only=None)
for i, g in df.groupby('date_trunc'):
    g.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(i), header=True, index_label=False, index=False)
    +---------+-------+---------------+-----------+
    |  Date   | Name  | Units of work | NewColumn |
    +---------+-------+---------------+-----------+
    | 12/1/16 | Alice |          6222 | median    |
    | 12/1/16 | Bob   |         14530 | median    |
    | 12/1/16 | Larry |         16887 | median    |
    +---------+-------+---------------+-----------+
```

I know I'm probably doing a lot wrong here, but I'd really appreciate some guidance.

What I want to end up with is a single csv with this:

```
+---------+--------+
|  Date   | Median |
+---------+--------+
| 12/1/16 |   1110 |
| 1/1/17  |   1400 |
| 2/1/17  |   1200 |
+---------+--------+
```

Comment: You lost me. You have a "given" Date in step 1, and then you want a csv of "distinct" Date"s" on step 5. What.

Comment: I'm looking for the median of all the Jan 2017 counts, median of all the Feb 2017 counts, all the Mar 2017 counts, etc...  I tried to clarify on #1 & #5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the following steps get you closer to your desired CSV output.

First, here's a clean rendition of the input DataFrame for anyone else looking to copy-paste into `pd.read_clipboard()`:

```
     Date     Name     Units of Work
0   Jan-17    Bob               450.0
1   Feb-17    Alice             300.0
2   Feb-17    Bob               450.0
3   Feb-17    Larry              50.0
4   Mar-17    Alice             400.0
5   Mar-17    Bob                11.0
6   Mar-17    Larry             100.0
7   Apr-17    Alice            1000.0
8   Apr-17    Bob               240.0
9   Apr-17    Larry              33.0
```

#### 0. Cast dates to python datetime (for sensible sort order)

```
# Docs on Python datetime format strings: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strip()), format='%b-%y')
```

#### 1. For each date, find the median units of work

```
meds = df.groupby('Date')[['Units of Work']].median()
meds
    Units of Work
Date    
2017-01-01  450.0
2017-02-01  300.0
2017-03-01  100.0
2017-04-01  240.0
```

#### 2, 3. Drop rows where units of work < 20% of that date's *median* units of work

```
# Set an index on which to merge the medians
df2 = df.set_index('Date')
# Pandas is smart enough to merge the 4-row meds DataFrame onto the 10-row df2 DataFrame based on matching index values
df2['Median'] = meds 

# Build a boolean mask to pick out "hard workers" and "slackers"
mask = df2['Units of Work'] >= 0.2 * df2['Median']

# "Hard workers," where units of work >= 20% of that date's median
df2[mask]
               Name  Units of Work  Median
Date                                      
2017-01-01   Bob             450.0   450.0
2017-02-01   Alice           300.0   300.0
2017-02-01   Bob             450.0   300.0
2017-03-01   Alice           400.0   100.0
2017-03-01   Larry           100.0   100.0
2017-04-01   Alice          1000.0   240.0
2017-04-01   Bob             240.0   240.0

# Bonus: "slackers," where units of work < 20% of that date's median
df2[~mask]
               Name  Units of Work  Median
Date                                      
2017-02-01   Larry            50.0   300.0
2017-03-01   Bob              11.0   100.0
2017-04-01   Larry            33.0   240.0
```

#### 4. For each date, multiply the number of "hard workers" by the median units of work

```
df2[mask].groupby('Date').size().mul(meds['Units of Work'])
2017-01-01    450.0
2017-02-01    600.0
2017-03-01    200.0
2017-04-01    480.0
```

Comment: Hey @peter-leimbigler thanks for the answer.  I was having some trouble with the format='%b-%y' on to_datetime.  I *think* I got it sorted out by adding  parse_dates=[0] on the read_csv, but now I'm getting an "AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'str'"

Comment: @SteveDallas good idea re: `parse_dates=[0]`. Where is this new error coming from? If you haven't already, try keeping `parse_dates=[0]` and also commenting out the entire `to_datetime` line. Alternatively, if you don't mind dates being sorted in lexicographic order (Apr, Feb, ...), you can try not using `parse_dates` and also not calling the `to_datetime` line. Then, if you wanted, you could cast the `Date` column from string to datetime in the final step, sort, and write to CSV.

Comment: the error was on the lambda.  A couple things I see though.  It looks like the mean is being computed rather than the median.  Additionally, I'm seeing all date rows.  Here are the first couple rows  
`| date  | user  | work | median |
|--------|-------|------|--------|
| 6/1/15 | Alice |    1 | 4      |
| 6/1/15 | Bob   |    7 | 4     |
`

Comment: sorry, having trouble figuring out how to add that table in the comments.

Comment: @SteveDallas, it's definitely the median that's being computed. The median is by definition the *middle* value of the input list. You can tell this is working because the numbers in this particular median list are members of the input list as well (all of the input dates have an odd number of rows, otherwise we'd see the *mean* of the middle two values). If the lambda is throwing an error, simply comment out that entire line (which I referred to above as "the `to_datetime` line") and try again. All it does is cast to `datetime`, which you might not need.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot about the 'even number records' condition.  Commenting out that line did help.  Now I seem to be running into a problem with the mask.  There are three rows on one date where the work value = 2 and the median = 50.5

Comment: @SteveDallas good to hear there's progress! I can't think of what might be causing this latest issue. Feel free to comment here or private-message me with more details (some example input that produces bad output would be good). Or it might be worth posting a new question!

Answer (score 0):

I'm around 80% sure I didn't understand the goal perfectly, but here's my attempt.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["Jan-12", "Jan-12"], "Name": ["Bob", "Alice"], "Work": [400, 300]})

def extract_rows_with_date(df, date):
    return df[df["Date"] == date]

# Extract unique dates
dates = df.Date.unique()

# Creating an empty dataframe dictionary (you get it)
new_df = {"Date": [], "Median": []}

for date in dates:
    # Fun stuff here
    date_df = extract_rows_with_date(df, date)
    median = date_df["Work"].median()

    above_20_median = date_df[date_df["Work"] > (median*20)/100]

    count_above_median = above_20_median.shape[0]

    new_df["Date"].append(date)
    new_df["Median"].append(count_above_median * median)


new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_df)
print(new_df.head())
```

Comment: Hey, thanks @wiggy-a. A couple weird things going on.  First is that my list of work is all integers.  I'm seeing a couple decimals in the list.  Also, it's only printing the first few dates.  Any idea why?